# Possessive form

Tags: possessive-s-vs-of

![The picture says "To form the possessive of any singular proper noun, add an apostrophe and an S. For example,
Venus's beauty
Dickens's reputation

But I saw somewhere,
Aeschylus'
Sophocles'
There is no S after apostrophe.
Which one is correct?]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0db3.jpg)

Comment: Not all possessive forms have "'s". For example, "my" and "your" lack both the apostrophe and the "s". [Here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/possessives) are some articles that may help.

Comment: When a word ends in s, it is up to the writer or editor to use an apostrophe s or just an apostrophe. Both are fine.

Comment: Moses' mission, Jesus' disciples, etc